# Cerrar conexiones generadas con knex.js automáticamente

Tags: nodejs, express, knex

¡Hola!,

Estoy trabajando en una api rest con node.js y express en el que utilizamos la librería knex.js para conectarnos a una base de datos de mysql.

El problema es que cuando realizamos varias peticiones a la api se quedan abiertas las conexiones. Consulté la doc de knex.js y vi que se podían cerrar.

La duda que tengo es si existe una forma de cerrar todas las conexiones a la bbdd cuando termine la petición ya que no quiero por ejemplo que cada vez que lance una excepción tenga que estar cerrando la conexión y meter un montón de líneas duplicadas en un script.

Gracias :)